# How to parse my JSON string into a multidimensional array in Javascript after passing JSON string from php file with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, parsing, multidimensional-array

I am doing some testing before I run a full scale program, and good thing I am.  I have been doing some tests to return a multidimensional array from my php file to my htm webpage.  I have tested many things to narrow my issue down to JSON.parse().  Here is my PHP code in file response.php:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<?php
$test = array(
array("first" => "Aaron", "last" => "Rodgers"),
array("first" => "Willie", "last" => "Makit")
);
//header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($test);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

and my output is normal:

```
{"0":{"first":"Aaron","last":"Rodgers"},"1":{"first":"Willie","last":"Makit"}} //New output as per object typecasting
```

Then on my htm file I am just trying to display the first name "Aaron" as an output after my button press.  here is the code for my html and javascript:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function ajaxTest(){
    var testAjax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    testAjax.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(testAjax.readyState==4)
        {
            var test1 = JSON.parse(testAjax.responseText);
            document.getElementById("doIt").innerHTML = test1.row[0].first;    //I believe my error might be an issue with my formatting on this line
        }
    }
    testAjax.open("GET", "response.php", true);
    testAjax.send(null);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="button" value="try it" onclick="ajaxTest()"/>
<div id="doIt"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried displaying the raw json string and that works.  But once I use JSON.parse() any data I try to display is blank.  I have tried several formats including the following:

```
document.getElementById("doIt").innerHTML = test[0][1];
... = test[0].first;
... = test;
... = test.length;
```

But regardless of the format I get no output (that is visible at least).  The part that puzzles me is that even my array.length will not display a value.  I get no error messages, just a blank output.  Thanks in advance for any pointers or fixes everyone.

edit: after type casting my outer array as an object I still only get blank outputs.  I do however think typecasting was necessary in my case.

Comment: you might find this link useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23146491/why-doesnt-json-parse-after-json-encode-doesnt-work

Comment: This code doesn't seem to have the same issue I am having.  I am not receiving any error messages.  I just get unviewable outputs once I use JSON.parse() when retrieving it with AJAX.

Comment: does that mean I should force it as an object by using json_encode($test, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT); in my php file?

Comment: otherwise how would I go about changing my output to JSON format?  I thought using json_encode() was all that was necessary.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670575/php-json-encode-json-force-object-mixed-object-and-array-output

Comment: I have typecasted my array and have updated my question above.  My output from my php is giving me what seems the proper format now, but I still get blank returns when I parse the data.  Do I not need to use JSON.parse() even though I have used json_encode()?

Comment: So instead of using echo do I just use a return command?  Because when I do not use JSON.parse() for my responseText I am able to retrieve the string still.  it's only when I parse it that my values become blank.

Comment: one way to find out is to debug your request and response in the browser, if you look at your response payload and headers via firebug or chrome debugger and paste it here we can know what's causing the problem.

Comment: you haven't set your content type:  header("Content-type: application/json"); you need to set it in your php code before json encode

Comment: The `(object)` cast is a mistake. If you want an array, you should leave it as an array instead of casting it to an object. @hyphenbash is incorrect in asserting that an array is not valid JSON. I do agree that it is generally better to wrap that array inside an object (not cast it to an object, but keep the array and wrap it an object), but it's valid JSON either way.

Comment: That helped me to figure out two things.  1) JSON.parse() is actually causing my program to freeze.  when I output the unparsed string it workes fine.  But if I make an arbitrary variable beforehand to simply store the JSON parsed string, my next line to display the unparsed string never runs.  and 2) my responseText is returning the html tags aswell as my echoed value (which I believe is causing the freeze).

Comment: how in my php to I return the my json string without the HTML tags.  when I tried changing the header like you suggested I recieved the following error message: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at response.php:6) in response.php on line 11

Comment: There must be some other PHP code running before the code you showed. Obviously there are not 11 lines in the code you listed.

Comment: Do you know how to use the JavaScript debugger in your browser? The JavaScript program isn't "freezing"; `JSON.parse()` is throwing an exception, quite a different thing. If you had the JavaScript console open, you would see the exception message. I urge you to get familiar with the JavaScript console and other developer tools available in your browser. For example, here is a great [introduction to the Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools).

Comment: In any case, `JSON.parse()` does not depend on HTML headers in the slightest. `JSON.parse()` takes a `String` argument. HTML headers are long out of the picture by this point.

Comment: the only exception is that I've excluded the <html><head></head><body></body> tags(each on their own line) and above is not posted the line 'header('Content-Type: application/json');' right before echo where I had my error

Comment: well I feel dumb now.  I removed the html tags from my php file and I can now pass values... Thanks you guys you've been a tremendous help.  I should have posted the html tags in my original post and I'm sure you guys would have noticed the error right away

Comment: Glad you sorted it out. I still recommend that you remove that `(object)` cast. Here is why: With the cast, you are not getting an array with a `.length` property, you're getting an object that is *almost* like an array but isn't. Presumably somewhere your code will need to know the length of the array - otherwise why have an array in the first place? If you remove the `(object)` cast you will get a proper array with a `.length` property.

Comment: in my final version I did remove the (object) casting.  It didn't seem to help me in this case, but I will remember it for projects I do in the future.  I will also be familiarizing myself more with the debugger as I haven't used one in a long time.

Comment: That is probably the best takeaway point out of this whole discussion. Using the JavaScript debugger and developer tools is like gaining a superpower. You will be able to solve problems quickly that were a complete mystery before. Just as an example, you would have *seen* the extraneous HTML tags by looking at `testAjax.responseText` in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

In the PHP file, remove the HTML tags.  That will solve the problem.  Otherwise when responseText is called from the .htm file the string will include the HTML tags and will cause a syntax error when the data is parsed with JSON.parse().

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your question - you've already solved the problem. But I wanted to follow up on a couple of comments, and an answer is the only way to do proper code formatting.

@hyphenbash made an excellent suggestion: wrap your array inside an object for the JSON output, instead of outputting the bare array. While JSON does allow an array at the top level (contrary to the comment that said this would be invalid JSON), there are advantages to using an object instead and putting the array as a property inside the object.

Consider the array version of your original JSON (before the `(object)` cast was added). It looked like this (with some formatting for readability):

```
[
    { "first":"Aaron", "last":"Rodgers" },
    { "first":"Willie", "last":"Makit" }
]
```

There is nothing wrong with that, but suppose you want to add something else to the JSON response that is *not* part of the array, perhaps some kind of status or error indication. There is no place to put it!

By contrast, suppose you wrapped the array in an object instead:

```
{
    data: [
        { "first":"Aaron", "last":"Rodgers" },
        { "first":"Willie", "last":"Makit" }
    ]
}
```

Now if you want to add some other bit of information it's easy:

```
{
    status: "test",
    data: [
        { "first":"Aaron", "last":"Rodgers" },
        { "first":"Willie", "last":"Makit" }
    ]
}
```

The PHP code to generate this is a simple change from your original:

```
<?php
$test = array(
    "status" => "test",
    "data" => array(
        array("first" => "Aaron", "last" => "Rodgers"),
        array("first" => "Willie", "last" => "Makit")
    )
);
echo json_encode($test);
?>
```

And it's equally easy to handle this in your JavaScript code:

```
var test1 = JSON.parse(testAjax.responseText);
document.getElementById("doIt").innerHTML = test1.data[0].first;
```

Note a couple of other little changes here that I recommend in JavaScript code:

- Take out the quotes around the `0` - either will work, but it's customary to use numeric indices with an array.
- Use `.foo` notation instead of `["foo"]` when accessing object properties. Either one works here too, but `.foo` is customary and more concise.

It is somewhat confusing to switch between PHP and JavaScript, since JavaScript has separate concepts of arrays and objects, where PHP combines them both into one.